# How to set automatically input values as empty (instead of "undefined") when the user remove the value?

Tags: angularjs, undefined, angular-ngmodel, is-empty

In Angular 1.6, when the user removes values inside inputs, these values are set up to "undefined". It seems to be the default behaviour in AngularJS.

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="name" class="form-control" id="inp_name"
       placeholder="My Name" required="true" value="" />
```

**Controller**

```
...
$scope.name = ""; <-- here the initial value is correctly set up as empty
...
$scope.submit = function(){
     alert($scope.name); <-- the value can be "undefined" if the user removed all the string
};
```

How to automatically set up the value as empty instead of "undefined" each time the text input is empty on the front-end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` to allow an empty string when the user deletes all the characters in an input box.

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-model-options Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/hKLPSqUHjJgmAswmg7NA?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "";
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <h1>ng-module-options DEMO</h1>
    <input ng-model="name" class="form-control" id="inp_name"
       placeholder="My Name" required="true" value="" 
       ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"
    />
    <br>
    name= {{name === undefined ? 'undefined': name}}
    <br>
    name= {{name === "" ? 'empty string': name}}
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your submit function:

```
$scope.name = $scope.name ? $scope.name : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no value in $scope.name (covers undefined) then setting it to empty string

```
if(!$scope.name){$scope.name="";}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative but an automatic way (which seems to be the best) is to use a function to check up if the value is empty, null and undefined.

**Controller**

```
$scope.isEmpty = function (value) {
   return angular.equals("", value) || angular.equals(undefined, value) || angular.equals(null, value);
};

//Usage 
$scope.submit = function(){
    if($scope.isEmpty($scope.name)) ...
};
```